# Getting : npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, nuxt.js, package.json

I have an old Nuxt.js package that was developed in Node 12 and I want to use it now with Node 16 (the latest stable) but when I try to install my packages by `npm install` I'm getting the versions difference errors.

But I know the packages are up to date. So, I'm trying to force clear my npm cache by `sudo npm cache clean -f` but I'm getting this error:

> npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.

The environment is `ubuntu 20.04` and this is my `package.json` file:

```json
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "generate": "nuxt generate"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/auth": "^4.9.1",
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.13.6",
    "@nuxtjs/dotenv": "^1.4.1",
    "@nuxtjs/google-adsense": "^1.4.0",
    "@nuxtjs/gtm": "^2.4.0",
    "@nuxtjs/router": "^1.6.1",
    "better-vue-input-tag": "^1.1.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.21.2",
    "core-js": "^3.19.2",
    "eslint": "^8.3.0",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "laravel-vue-pagination": "^2.3.1",
    "node-sass": "^6.0.1",
    "nuxt": "^2.15.8",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "sass-loader": "^12.3.0",
    "vform": "^2.1.2",
    "vue-autosuggest": "^2.2.0",
    "vue-gtag": "^1.16.1",
    "vue-infinite-loading": "^2.4.5",
    "vue2-google-maps-withscopedautocomp": "^0.12.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "ip": "^1.1.5",
    "prettier": "^2.5.0"
  }
}
```

How can I use the force flag without getting errors?

**Edit:**

The errors that I'm getting for versions difference:
[image]

Comment: What are those `I'm getting the versions difference errors`? Also, using `sudo` with `npm` is usually not a good idea. Some packages are maybe just not compatible with node 16. Last time I checked (few days ago), it was still v14 if I'm not mistaken. There are some results on Google with the given error, maybe give it a read. Also, if you do have issues with NPM and it's annoying to debug, I'd say to give a try to yarn or PNPM at that point.

Comment: @kissu Thank you first of all. I googled and checked the links but the problem is not solved yet. No, the latest version is 16 so, I need to use node 16 for my other projects in my system. I will try by yarn or PNPM by the way. thanks.

Comment: Those are warnings and not errors.

Comment: @kissu I want to force clear the cache. How can I do this?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

So I was having the same problem as you and I thought that the caching didn't work, but in reality it worked it was just a warning message, try this command `npm cache verify` to verify if the caching worked or not and if it worked your problem is not with the caching but the problem is probably with your node version.

```
PS C:\code>  npm cache clean --force
npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
PS C:\code> npm cache verify
Cache verified and compressed (~\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_cacache)
Content verified: 0 (0 bytes)
Index entries: 0
Finished in 0.008s
PS C:\code>
```

Comment: I have the same problem but when I try to do `npm cache verify`, `npm` answers me `Not found: verify`, so what to do in this case?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an issue with the current version of Node installed on your device. If you try to reinstall on top of the previous installation, or use the @latest command it won't work. Please uninstall Node then reinstall again from the offical website.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar challenge, and even after running `npm cache verify` as suggested by @AmineTech, it still gave this error:

```
HeroProject % npm cache verify
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall unlink
npm ERR! path /Users/hero/.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/04/b2/374e5d535b73ef97bd25df2ab763ae22f9ac29c17aac181616924a8cb676d782b303fb28fbae15b492e103c7325a6171a3116e6881aa4a34c10a34c8e26c
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Your cache folder contains root-owned files, due to a bug in
npm ERR! previous versions of npm which has since been addressed.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! To permanently fix this problem, please run:
npm ERR!   sudo chown -R 501:20 "/Users/hero/.npm"

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/hero/.npm/_logs/2023-02-23T08_40_35_499Z-debug-0.log
```

but it came with a hint on what to do next.

It happened that I recently updated my Node.js version and a couple changes occurred behind the scenes; Some file and directory changed ownership. No time for all the details. I went ahead and picked the line `sudo chown -R 501:20 "/Users/hero/.npm"` and ran that in terminal again.

Afterwards, I was able to successfully run `npm cache verify`.

```
HeroProject % npm cache verify                                 
Cache verified and compressed (~/.npm/_cacache)
Content verified: 263 (3665196 bytes)
Content garbage-collected: 20 (1357860 bytes)
Missing content: 8
Index entries: 263
Finished in 0.439s
```

!!! Please note that this happened on a Mac.