# I have npm install errror 'react'

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-install

npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\valami\frontend_react\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v18.12.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v8.4.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\kissm\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-11-12T15_42_41_826Z-debug-0.log

can you guys help me

I tried clean the cache but when i run the command i got another problems:

npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.

Comment: The `npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.

` is answered here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70180990/getting-npm-warn-using-force-recommended-protections-disabled

Answer (score 0):

This is far from specific enough to give exact answer as to what's wrong, but seeing it's gyp throwing the error, I would be almost sure, you don't have gyp deps. Meaning Visual C++ Build Environment and Python 3.7 higher.

Here is what you need to configure it: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-gyp

Answer (score -2):

I think you should replace node-sass with sass as package dependency